# Make a entry mandatory if exist in a table

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the next design doubt:

I have `athlete` entity, the `athlete` can have many nationalities, so I have second table called `countries`. Then between `athlete` and `countries` there is a many-to-many relationship. I create another table `athlete_country` to resolve the many-to-many relationship.

My question: Is there a way to achieve that `athlete_country` entry be mandatory for any entry in the `athlete` table?

I am working on postgresql. Is there a way in another database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do it this way for logical reason: athlete_country tables references athlete table, and if you do back reference (in fact you can do it) you will not be able to insert any row in either table because each row should reference to the row in another table, which isn't inserted yet.

The solution is to use many-to-one relationship in addition to many-to-many which you have described. For example, you can add "primary_country" field to athlete table which references directly to the country table. In that case you can be sure that any athlete has relationship with at least one country, specified in "primary_country" field and, optionally, with other countries listed in the athlete_country table.

```
create table country(id serial primary key, name text);
create table athlete(id serial primary key, name text, primary_country int references country(id));
create table athlete_country(athlete_id int references athlete(id), country_id int references country(id), primary key (athlete_id, country_id));
```